# Strange problem with libc: undefined reference to `crypt'

Tags: compiling, libraries

I moved from Archlinux to Kubuntu 12.04 yesterday.

I compiled buildroot 2012.08 on Archlinux without any problem. Though on Kubuntu `libcrypt` seems to be broken. `sysvinit` can't find it anywhere. `glibc-dev` and all dependencies are installed.

How do I link to `libcrypt`? Or, which package containts that library?

```
...
bc-gcc   sulogin.o    -o sulogin
sulogin.o: In function `main':
sulogin.c:(.text+0x49d): undefined reference to `crypt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 9):

Try adding '-lcrypt' after any objects used in linking; I've had a couple of instances where gcc would complain about crypt if -lcrypt wasn't near the end of the link list.

In other words, try something like:

```
gcc -D FOO -D BAR -W -Wall -pedantic -O2 foo.o bar.o -lnsl -lcrypt -o baz
```

as opposed to

```
gcc -D FOO -D BAR -W -Wall -pedantic -O2 -lnsl -lcrypt foo.o baz.o -o baz
```

Answer (score 4):

undefined reference to 'crypt' is a linker error.

Try linking with -lcrypt : `gcc ....-lcrypt`

Comment: No. It tries to link, but can't. Configuration script changes linkage options. Specifically `buildroot` sets variable `LCRYPT="-lcrypt"`

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using super-auto-magical CMAKE like me, try to add

```
target_link_libraries(your_binary_name PRIVATE libcrypt.so)
```

to your *CMakeLists.txt*

Alternatively, replace PRIVATE for PUBLIC as needed..

---

If you have well established paths to libraries (e.g. all needed libs in /usr/lib), you may be fine with just stating in *CMakeLists.txt*:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lcrypt")`